# Trying to build for IPhone "The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP"

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to build an app with the settings `[Debug | Iphone]` or `[Release | Iphone]` and I always get the following errors in the monodevelop Deploy to Device window:

```
Installing application
Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8008017
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

The XCode Organizer device log shows this going on during the install

```
Tue Jul 19 10:30:54 unknown installd[1527] <Error>: 2ff68000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -393026204
Tue Jul 19 10:30:54 unknown installd[1527] <Error>: 2ff68000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.7XofYW/My-App.app
Tue Jul 19 10:30:54 unknown installd[1527] <Error>: 2ff68000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Tue Jul 19 10:30:54 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[1526] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
```

I have a provisioning profile that has worked always for this app, I've read that the bundle identifier has to be correct but my app id is randomnumbers.* so shouldn't any bundle ID work?  I have tried to make (unsuccessfully) an ad-hoc provisioning profile over the last day or so, but the build options are pointing at the correct provisioning profile and "Identity" which I'm assuming is representative of the certificate to use with the provisioning profile.

Any help to put me in the right direction would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after spending 2 days trying to figure it out I opted for the nuclear option and just deleted all my development and distribution provisioning profiles and certificates, created new ones, created a new solution and associated projects, and added copied all the files from the broken project to the new projects.  Debug to IPhone... voila works perfectly.

I haven't tried to do a distribution publish, and I don't intend to until the app is 100% ready now.

I tried every possible combination of settings in monodevelop and learned way more about what happens after you hit the play button than I'd ever care to know, all to no avail.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Just had this under Xamarin Studio. Simply doing a Build->Clean All and trying again worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Monodevelop 2.6b3.

It turned out I had to add in the codesign argument as a custom after build command. Code signing was not happening due to me having add the Default.png cp command to work around the Default.png not automatically being included into the app package bug.

Example below:

cp /Users/chris/path_to_app/Default.png /Users/chris/path_to_app/bin/iPhone/Release/application.app/Default.png
${SolutionDir}

codesign -v -f -s "iPhone Developer: chris xxx" "--resource-rules=/Users/chris/path_to_app/bin/iPhone/Release/application.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/chris/path_to_app/bin/iPhone/Release/application.xcent" "/Users/chris/path_to_app/bin/iPhone/Release/application.app"
${SolutionDir}

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when I tried to debug application with "IPad only" application setting on my iPhone. Changing "iPhone Application" setting to "iPhone and iPad" solved the problem